# Is it worth noting that a "contributor" is pretending to be a character from a TV show?

Tags: discussion

In particular, he's using the name and (slightly redacted) bio of the main character from the TV show [Dark Justice](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0101073/?ref_=ttmi_tt).

Comment: How's that different than pretending to be any other character? Isn't pretending to be fictional characters a time honored internet activity?

Comment: [Waves to user Shogo Makishima, who has 29k rep, but has been a little quiet for the past couple of years. Used to be a regular under (what I assume was) his RL name.]

Comment: In what context would it be "worth noting" something like this?

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe it is.

As far as I can tell, it's only the user's *profile* that's based on the TV show character. There are very few rules about what you can and can't put in your profile, and none of those rules say you can't mock up your profile to look like a fictional character.

If they were actually trying to role-play as the character, that *would* be a problem, but their network-wide contributions appear to be genuine and in their own voice (albeit of dubious quality). Therefore, I don't believe that their profile is noteworthy, or that anything needs to be done about it.